# Runtime Error: could not start server

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a client server program in Qt that client send some message to server but during compile the "startserver" function can't run and i get the following error:could not start server. Could you please say where is problem?

"main.cpp"

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mythread.h"
#include "myserver.h"
#include "QtSql/QtSql"
#include "QMessageBox"
#include "mainwindow.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

myserver server;
server.startserver();

MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

"myserver.h"

```
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "QTcpServer"
#include "mythread.h"
#include "QTcpSocket"


 namespace Ui
 {
  class myserver;
}


class myserver : public QObject

{
 Q_OBJECT

public:

server(QObject * parent = 0);

explicit myserver(QObject *parent = 0);

void startserver();


public slots:

void acceptConnection();

protected:


void incomingConnections(qintptr socketDescriptor);

QTcpSocket* c_client;
QTcpServer s_server;

private:
qintptr socketDescriptor;


 };

#endif
```

"myserver.cpp"

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "mythread.h"


myserver::myserver(QObject *parent) :

QObject(parent)
 {
 }

void myserver::startserver()
{

int port = 1234;

if(s_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
  {
    qDebug() << "Could not start server";
  }
 else
  {
    qDebug() << "Listening to port " ;
  }

 }

void myserver::incomingConnections(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
  mythread *thread = new mythread(socketDescriptor,this);

  qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

  connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

  thread->start();
}


void myserver::acceptConnection()

{

  c_client = s_server.nextPendingConnection();

  connect(c_client,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(startRead()));

  qDebug() << " Connecting...";

}
```

Comment: A "compiler error" is an error from the *compiler*, something you get when you *build* your program. The message you get is from the already compiled and linked program when you *run* it.

Comment: As for *why* you get the error message, you really should try and [print the underlying error you get](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#errorString), there may be many reasons the `listen` call fails (including someone else using the port, have you tried using another port number?)

Comment: yes.. exactly it was for my port number.thanks in advance

Comment: I change the port number.. when i run server for first time i get the error:could not start server bud when i compile it again it work...  what is the matter?

Comment: You should [read more about TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), especially learn about [the protocol operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) and [the different states a TCP socket can have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/media/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg). Most likely you experience the `TIME_WAIT` state. Also search for and read about *socket options* and especially the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(s_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
{
  qDebug() << "Could not start server";
}
else
{
  qDebug() << "Listening to port " ;
}
```

reads as "if the server CAN listen to any address on given port, print `could not start server`"

just change it to `if (!s_server.listen(...))` and the missleading message should be gone